# Javascript parse RSS which includes German characters

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to load rss which has German characters included (ö, ä, ü...)

xhrRequest.responseText already contains converted characters (\u00f ...)

Without manually replacing is there to force right encoding so original characters stay visible?

```
var url = 'https://apolut.net/feed/podcast/'

    xhrRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhrRequest.readyState == 4) {

            
        }
    }
    xhrRequest.onerror = function(e) { 
       
    };
    xhrRequest.open('GET', url);
    xhrRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    xhrRequest.send();
```

I do have utf on the top of page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After receiving the data, use `decodeURIComponent()` to turn the Unicode to text again with the character.

```
xhrRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhrRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhrRequest.status == 200) {
            var decodedResponse = decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse(xhrRequest.responseText));
    decodedResponce= decodedResponce.contents
            // Now decodedResponse contains the original characters
            console.log(decodedResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

If your received response is not json,

```
xhrRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhrRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhrRequest.status == 200) {
            var decodedResponse = xhrRequest.responseText
            // Now decodedResponse contains the original characters
            console.log(decodedResponse);
        }
    }
}
``
```

Comment: I am getting  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 3 (line 1 column 4)  at JSON.parse

Comment: Ok can you send an example of the response of the xhr before my code? Also is your data received json?

Comment: Without using decodeURIComponent I get this as response:  https://pastecode.io/s/2ffp88ry   I have content type is text/xml, but if I change it to "application/json" I stil get same response.

Comment: Ok try the first code snippet again

Comment: I tried that before and there is an error I mentioned.

Comment: No I changed it to fit the format of the sample response you gave

Comment: decodedResponse.contents is undefined.

Comment: It shouldn’t be like that since your example included a contents key

Comment: Well you can try using the code shown in my original post, there is nothing else.